# Turn up, Turn down (direction)

Tags: adverbs

Are there "turn up", "turn down" in addtion to "turn left" and "turn right" ?

Comment: ***turn over, turn [a]round, turn back, turn in, turn out, turn from, turn against,...*** Why single out the prepositions ***up*** and ***down*** as "special cases" for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are natural, common phrases. The 'up' and 'down' don't have any particular meaning; there might or might not be a hill, and they don't indicate any definite direction. But it would be unnatural to say "Go to the dead end and turn the street", something needs to be after 'turn'. So "Go to the dead end and turn up the street." Hopefully there's only one way to turn at that dead end, or there's an obvious hill.

Comment: And naturally, **turn up** means arrive somewhere (generally without warning) and **turn down** means reject (an offer, job or similar).

Answer (score 0):

The phrases "turn up" (meaning "turn in an upward direction") and "turn down" do exist, but they're extremely rare, since people, and the vast majority of vehicles, are incapable of turning up or down.

As you know, if you're walking along a path, it's impossible for you to turn up or down because it's impossible for you to walk above or below the path; you can only walk *on* the path. And, of course, the same goes for cars: it's impossible for a car to go up above the road or down below it.

Airplanes can turn up and down, but pilots very rarely actually use the phrases "turn up" and "turn down" to describe this. Instead, they say things like "climb" (go up), "descend" (go down), and "level off" (stop going up or down).

Nevertheless, to me, it sounds more or less normal to say something like, "The rocket was traveling west, then it turned up."